# what'd would be the best way to read external storage for audio files and return them as a list on java?

Tags: java, android

So the idea i have is i want to make a plugin in java that'd read up on all audio files on external storage and return them as a list that i'd be able to use , what would be the easiest way to do so ?

Comment: use the [mediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore)

Answer (score 0):

Using content provider OR uri you can easily access all kind of mp3 file get and show easily into listview